# slow picture taking and processing on windows store app

Tags: c#, image, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows store app used in a Surface RT.
It's basically a questionnaire with 3 pictures required per questionnaire. 
This is how I preview and take the picture

```
    async public void TakePictureFor(RackAuditQuestions q)
    {
        CameraCaptureUI cameraUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
        cameraUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = false;
        cameraUI.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.MediumXga;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile capturedMedia = await cameraUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);            
        if (capturedMedia != null)
        {                
            using (var streamCamera = await capturedMedia.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapCamera = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapCamera.SetSource(streamCamera);
                // This display the image in a bound object to the XAML
                q.Image = bitmapCamera;                    
                int width = bitmapCamera.PixelWidth;
                int height = bitmapCamera.PixelHeight;
                q.pictureStream = await capturedMedia.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            }
        }
    }
```

After around 7 days of heavy use* the taking a single picture takes about 18+ seconds from the moment I touch the screen until control returns back to the user. I made a [video of this. To illustrate it better](http://youtu.be/bE7-Uzoqr3M).

*by heavy use I mean 100 pictures a day. Reinstalling the app makes it all work fine again, but not restarting the surface or the app

I am out of idea since the taking picture process is basically delegated to the OS. I don't know where to look. Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CaptureFileAsync(like i am) turns out there is a copy of the pictures being store in the temp folder here: 
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Packages{your-package-guid}\TempState
(you set the name of your package in the Package.appxmanifest)

You can get a list of the files in your code by doing

```
StorageFolder temp = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await temp.GetFilesAsync();
```

I just delete them all when i submit the data to a server, but that depends on you. 
Hoipe this helps anyone who gets stuck with this problem as it helped me.